# How to show an image background while the video background loads in parallax?

Tags: parallax

How to show an image background while the video background loads in parallax?

Anyone know how we would achieve this effect? We are using a high-res video background that looks great, but it takes a moment to load and thus the user may scroll past before it loads.

images

Comment: I believe you got a negative hit on this thread because you didn't show any attempt to figure it out by displaying code or different methods of what you have tried. Next time do so. Cheers!

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand how to use the forum effectively. I haven't figure it out just yet, but I'm going to take a look at your code below. I'm using a nice wordpress them so would this code somewhere in the page or in a functions.php?

Comment: No problem. There are some plugins available in wordpress to help you along with this video issue. Perhaps trying one of them if want simplicity or have a look at html5 posters.. search that in google and it should help you out a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML5

The poster attribute specifies an image to be shown while the video is downloading, or until the user hits the play button. If this is not included, the first frame of the video will be used instead.

I would use some jquery.

```
 (function($) {
    $(function() {
      var videobackground = new $.backgroundVideo($('#bgVideo'), {
        "align" : "centerXY",
        "path" : "assets/img/",
        "width": 1280,
        "height": 720,
        "filename" : "guate",
        "types" : ["mp4", "ogg", "webm"],
        "poster" : "imagehere.jpg"
    });
```

The poster is standard now a days with HTML5.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_poster.asp